# 78% cease calculation and "no message" from QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to generate an outline of multiple elevation lines which I can use to cut into some other elevation lines. I understand that I can buffer and dissolve to get the result I'm after, but whenever I try this the calculation runs to 78% and then stops, and I get a very short popup message on my task bar that says "no message."

I'm running an I7 12 core, 64 bit, 32GB ram, QGIS v 2.6.1.

Comment: You could try to only calculate your stuff on a subset of your data. That way you can see if there is a general problem with the workflow you want to perform, or if it "merely" is a problem with the data amount. Also: do you use a 64 bit QGis? If you use 32 bit this will only be able to use about 3,5 GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks - I cut the data in half and it is now working. I'm using the 64bit QGIS so I don't know why this was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a convex hull using the vector tool menu and generate a single feature "create single minimum convex hull". I think that will give you the outline of the line features you are looking for.